# Recursively copy and rename to replace spaces with underscore

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, rename

I have a directory with 400 sub-directories each containing several hundred files many with filenames that contain spaces. I need to copy all of the files with spaces in the filenames, resulting two copies of those files, one with spaces and one with underscores replacing the spaces. I see a lot of code that comes close, but nothing that will copy, rename and replace spaces recursively. Any suggestions ??? Thanks....RW [Linux rename using parameters and spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/100941/linux-rename-using-parameters-and-spaces)
Linux rename using parameters and spaces?

Answer (score 1):

And yet it is not too difficult:

```
 for i in "$(find . -type f -name '* *' -print)"; do cp "$i" $(echo $i | sed 's/ /_/g'); done
```

This assumes your directory names do **not** contain spaces. If they do, the following bash script will work:

```
  #!/bin/bash

 TGT=/path/to/targt/directory
 LIST="$(find $TGT -type f -name '* *' -print)"
 for i in $LIST; do 
      dirpath=${i%/*}
      base=base=${i##*/}
      newbase=$(echo "base" | sed 's/ /_/g')
      cp "$i" $dirpath/$newbase
 done
```

If your directory names contain spaces, and you want those dulicated, you will have to specify better what you want to duplicate: the original files and the new ones, only the new ones, possible other files without spaces...

Comment: Thanks....
The directory names do not contain spaces.

Comment: @user2693196 if it works, you should accept my answer, so that users with similar problems searching for a solution may find it and be encouraged to use it.This both yields a faster response, and prevents a new useless post from being submitted.